# Audio recording is empty on safari ios

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, recordrtc

I've used RecordRTC in order to record audio and send it to a speech-to-text API.

Somehow, it all works perfectly fine except for using Safari IOS. 
While using Safari IOS, the recording which I'm retrieving as base64 string,
is somehow returned empty from the recorder object.

Previous questions asked about it were answered to use another library,
yet the docs for RecordRTC specifically says it fully supports Safari IOS.

Could you please help me figuring out the problem and finding a workaround? 
My code:

```
    async initMic() {
      let stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: false, audio: true});
      mic = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, { 
        type: 'audio',
        mimeType: 'audio/wav',
        recorderType: RecordRTC.StereoAudioRecorder,
        sampleRate: 48000,
        numberOfAudioChannels: 1,
      });
    },

    async sendRecording() {
      let vm = this;
      mic.stopRecording(function() {
        mic.getDataURL(function(dataURL) {
            vm.$store.dispatch('UpdateAudioBase64', dataURL.replace('data:audio/wav;base64,', ''));
            mic.reset();
            vm.$emit('send-recording');
        });
      });
    },
```

** The string 'replace' function is meant to remove the base64 header
    before sending it to speech-to-text API (API's needs).

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

If not mistaken, apple fu... messed up again with their dumb policy,
problem is you can't do a lot of things(like setting up recorder)
without USER trigger them,

so you should wrap your recorder in click event listener, 
user click button, then your `mic = new RecordRTCPromisesHandler(stream, {... etc`
fires and recording starts.

check this example https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC/blob/master/simple-demos/audio-recording.html

here this trick works

btw your code works in mac safari?